# When I run node js I receive an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, authentication, syntax-error

I am trying to connect to my API using the following code, I run API athuntication login javascript code by using node filename.html. It is showing the following error. [Binance API Doc](https://github.com/binance-us). Please, any suggestion?

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

The API login code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var burl = 'https://api.binance.com';
    var endPoint = '/api/v3/account';
    var dataQueryString = 'recvWindow=20000&timestamp=' + Date.now();
    
    var keys = {
        'akey' : 'xxxxxxxx',
        'skey' : 'xxxxxxxx'
    }
    
    var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dataQueryString ,keys['skey']);
    
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    var url = burl + endPoint + '?' + dataQueryString + '&signature=' + signature;
    
    ourRequest.open('GET', url, true);
    ourRequest.setRequestHeader('X-MBX-APIKEY',keys['akey']);
    
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
        ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        console.log(ourData);
    }
    ourRequest.send();
    
    
</script>
</html>
```

The crypto-js.js file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZB5zTCpaz2M_01KcOZa1HLWDtAQOlKQ3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try using, `type="text/javascript"` in the script tag

Comment: it's already "<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js.js"></script>
"

Comment: No, not that script tag. It is the next script block.

Comment: Yes I tried that, the same error. It might be the crypto-js.js. Do you know how can I remove crypto-js.js from the script?

Comment: why are writing the script in an empty HTML file using it as a browser level import? what are you trying to achieve? Why don't you the js code to node.js file

Comment: "Why don't you the js code to node.js file" .. I wish I know how to do that. I thought this is the only way to run js in node

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project folder and run `npm init -y` and then `npm i crypto-js --save` and follow the below steps:

1. create a filename.js file
2. const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
3. include the logic that you wrote between the script tags after this line
4. Run it in the command line using the command `node filename.js`

Comment: In filename.js I will write the following: const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js.js"></script>

Comment: not this, the other script content. Do not include script tags.

Comment: Got it I will do it now

Comment: Don't worry! you will get through this. Start learning stuff online https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ which will get you to the speed. Good luck! learning

Comment: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\BinanceUS_Project\Signed-REST-API-master\Signed-REST-API-master\filename.js:13:22)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/

Comment: Thank you for your support. I get the following error

Comment: Do you have any idea why I am getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: You need to go through the basic tutorial to understand this part. Hint: The logic you moved is the browser level logic. The same thing you need to implement in node.js. Again I would recommend you go through a basic online courses.

Comment: Ok cool I will study that, can I keep in touch with you for further questions ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: You may add a comment here on your progress. I will help you!

Comment: could you check out the question on the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191658/fetch-price-from-signed-binance-api